# R: Predicting with lmer, y ~ . formula error

Tags: r, lme4

Predicting values in new data from an lmer model throws an error when a period is used to represent predictors. Is there any way around this?

The answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271290/formula-issue-when-predicting-using-lmer) offers a way to automatically write out the full formula instead of using the period, but I'm curious if there's a way to get predictions from new data just using the period.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
mydata <- data.frame(
    groups = rep(1:3, each = 100),
    x = rnorm(300),
    dv = rnorm(300)
)

train_subset <- sample(1:300, 300 * .8)
train <- mydata[train_subset,]
test <- mydata[-train_subset,]

# Returns an error
mod <- lmer(dv ~ . - groups + (1 | groups), data = train)
predict(mod, newdata = test)
predict(mod) # getting predictions for the original data works

# Writing the full formula without the period does not return an error, even though it's the exact same model
mod <- lmer(dv ~ x + (1 | groups), data = train)
predict(mod, newdata = test)
```

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: Error in terms.formula(formula(x, fixed.only = TRUE)): '.' in formula and no 'data' argument
Traceback:

1. predict(mod, newdata = test)
2. predict.merMod(mod, newdata = test)
3. get.orig.levs(object, fixed.only = TRUE)
4. terms(object, ...)
5. terms.merMod(object, ...)
6. terms.formula(formula(x, fixed.only = TRUE))

Comment: this looks like it might be an lme4 bug ... ??

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed in the development branch of lme4 now. You can install from GitHub (see first line below) or wait a few weeks (early April-ish) for a new version to hit CRAN.

```r
remotes::install_github("lme4/lme4") ## you will need compilers etc.
mydata <- data.frame(
    groups = rep(1:3, each = 100),
    x = rnorm(300),
    dv = rnorm(300)
)

train_subset <- sample(1:300, 300 * .8)
train <- mydata[train_subset,]
test <- mydata[-train_subset,]

# Returns an error
mod <- lmer(dv ~ . - groups + (1 | groups), data = train)
p1 <- predict(mod, newdata = test)

mod2 <- lmer(dv ~ x + (1 | groups), data = train)
p2 <- predict(mod2, newdata = test)
identical(p1, p2) ## TRUE
```